# How to fix "model.predict is not a function" (tensorflow.js)?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I wanted to test lack of errors code bellow:

```
'use strict'

const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const { createCanvas, createImageData } = require('canvas');

const canvas = createCanvas(800, 600);

async function load_model() {
    let m = await tf.loadLayersModel('path/to/model.json')
    return m;
}

let model = load_model();

model.then(function (res) {
    const example = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);
    const prediction = model.predict(example);
    console.log(prediction);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But i got one)
And it tells `TypeError: model.predict is not a function`. Why is it happened? i use this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras) as tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`predict` is on the promise returned by then

```
model.then(function (res) {
    const example = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);
    const prediction = res.predict(example);
    console.log(prediction);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: can you explain what this means? I don't understand